# Input Sequences using CSV-Reader and Queues in Tensorflow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

Referring to: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/

**GOAL:**

I would like to train a LSTM using preceding sequences in the following form:
[t0 t1 t2], [t1 t2 t3], [t2 t3 t4] ...

Furthermore these sequences should also shuffled.
e.g. [t2 t3 t4], [t0 t1 t2], [t1 t2 t3] ...

My data are stored in a csv-file, each row representing a time step. The columns contain the different features & target value.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way to feed shuffled coherent sequences using **csv-reader and queues (not placeholder and feed_dict)** in Tensorflow?
I cannot think of a way to implement that with: tf.TextLineReader() and tf.train.shuffle_batch().

My workaround does what it's supposed to, but is horribly slow:

```
train_filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([path])
rand_ind_q = tf.train.range_input_producer(data_len-seq_len, shuffle=True)

def read_csv(filename_queue, ncols, header_lines):
''' returns a list of tensors with content of csv-file
'''
    # content <- [(data_len,) ... ncols ... (data_len,)]

    whole_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, content = whole_reader.read(filename_queue)
    content = tf.string_split([content], delimiter='\n').values[header_lines:]  
    record_defaults = ncols*[[0.]]
    content = tf.decode_csv(content, record_defaults, field_delim=',')
    return content

def slice_seq(q, content, seq_len):
''' returns a list of tensors with sequences
'''
    # seq <- [(1,seq_len,) ... ncols ... (1,seq_len,)]

    start_ind = q.dequeue()

    seq = list(map(lambda tensor: tf.slice(tensor, [start_ind], [seq_len]), content))
    seq = list(map(lambda tensor: tf.reshape(tensor, (1,seq_len,)), seq))
    return seq
```

Answer (score 0):

How large is the csv file you are loading? If it is large, then using WholeFileReader is problematic; if it is small, then I would suggest creating the sequences outside TensorFlow.

That said, if you want to do this in TensorFlow, you could try

```
block_size = 10
seq_len = 3
batch_size = 4
queue_capacity = 32
num_threads = 4
csv_path = '/path/to/some.csv'

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_path])
block = tf.TextLineReader().read_up_to(filename_queue, block_size).values
subsequences = [tf.slice(block, [i], [block_size - seq_len + 1]) for i in range(seq_len)]
batched = tf.train.shuffle_batch(subsequences,
                                 batch_size, 
                                 capacity=queue_capacity,
                                 min_after_dequeue=queue_capacity/2,     
                                 num_threads=num_threads,
                                 enqueue_many=True)
decoded = [tf.decode_csv(b, [[0.]] * ncols, ',') for b in batched]
```

The only downside here is that you will miss roughly seq_len/batch_size of the subsequences.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, definitely faster than the WholeFilerReader-Version! Still need to play around a bit to check whether that's faster than using placeholder+feed_dict.

Comment: The sequence length here looks like 'block_size-seq_len+1', which should have been 'seq_len', right? Secondly, what is block_size? Total number of samples stored in the csv file?